# Length of line in function defaults to 1 after first user input, why?

Tags: c, while-loop, max, c-strings

I am practicing an algorithm from the C programming book and want to output the length of each line after it is typed. After I write a sentence, it gives me the correct out put of "This is a line of length 10" or something. Then in keeps repeating "This is a line of length 1" over and over until I control +z. How can I get it to just print the length and then continue to receive input each time?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input line size */

int getlines(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print longest input line */

int main()
{
    int len; /* current line length */
    int max; /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /*longest line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getlines(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        printf("This is the line length %d.", len);
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0) /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getlines(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you to find a better title as the current one hardly has any meaning since `getlines()` is not a standard C function, but one you defined yourself.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I made the change. Hopefully it is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to enclose statements of the while loop in  braces and you need to change the condition of the loop.

```
while ((len = getlines(line, MAXLINE)) > 1 )
{
    printf("This is the line length %d.", len);
    if (len > max) {
        max = len;
        copy(longest, line);
    }
}
```

Or the condition in the while loop can look like

```
while ((len = getlines(line, MAXLINE)) != 0 && line[0] != '\n' )
```

Pay attention to that the second parameter of the function copy should have the qualifier const

```
void copy(char to[], const char from[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran it and its ok. However you need to note that you were using max which is a keyword and hence your code will not work. see [here](https://codeforwin.org/2016/02/c-program-to-find-maximum-and-minimum-using-functions.html) for more information on max

I modified it a little to help you see better:

```
int main()
{
    int len; /* current line length */
    int maxVal; /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    //char longest[MAXLINE]; /*longest line saved here */

    maxVal = 0;
    printf("Enter Input: ");
    while ((len = getlines(line, MAXLINE)) > 0){
        printf("This is the line length %d.\n", len);
        if (len > maxVal) {
            maxVal = len;
            //copy(longest, line);
            printf("Longest Line is now: %s", line);
        }   
        printf("Enter Input: ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can use this if there is no other need for longestLine since all you wanted was to print it based on your code

The output was as follow when tested:

> Enter Input: Hello
>
> This is the line length 6.
>
> Longest Line is now: Hello
>
> Enter Input: World
>
> This is the line length 6.
>
> Enter Input: Worldly Affairs
>
> This is the line length 16.
>
> Longest Line is now: Worldly Affairs
>
> Enter Input: Hello World
>
> This is the line length 12.
>
> Enter Input: